# Google drive python SDK throwing SSL errors

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api

I have the following method being used in my Flask app to create folders in my Google drive if they do not exist. If they do exist then their folder_id is returned.

```
def find_or_create_folder_in_google_drive(name, parent_id=None):
    query = f"name='{name}'"

    if parent_id:
        query += f" and '{parent_id}' in parents"
    query += " and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    query += " and trashed=false"

    response = (
        GOOGLE_DRIVE_SERVICE.files()
        .list(q=query, spaces="drive", fields="files(id, name)")
        .execute()
    )
    files = response.get("files", [])

    if not files:
        file_metadata = {"name": name, "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}

        if parent_id:
            file_metadata["parents"] = [parent_id]

        folder = (
            GOOGLE_DRIVE_SERVICE.files()
            .create(body=file_metadata, fields="id")
            .execute()
        )
        return folder.get("id")

    return files[0].get("id")
```

This snippet works flawlessly, tested many times, when sending in a payload from Postman and Thunder Client VSCode extension. However issues arise when sending the same payload from my frontend react app to my flask app. The following exception is thrown

```
  File "path/backend/storage_manager/google/prompts.py", line 19, in create_or_get_prompts_path_google_sheets
    root_folder_id = find_or_create_folder_in_google_drive(ROOT_FOLDER)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/storage_manager/google_services/get_drive_paths.py", line 15, in find_or_create_folder_in_google_drive
    .execute()
     ^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1724, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1396, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1278, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1134, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] record layer failure (_ssl.c:2576)
```

Which stems from this line

```
response = (
        GOOGLE_DRIVE_SERVICE.files()
        .list(q=query, spaces="drive", fields="files(id, name)")
        .execute()
)
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Not sure what else to do here as it's working fine with API calling tools but not with frontend app. Maybe a CORS issue?

I am using the following google dependencies for reference

```
google-api-core==2.16.1
google-api-python-client==2.116.0
google-auth==2.27.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.62.0
```

Comment: Show us logging of the generated `query`, please, for both success + fail cases.

Comment: @J_H thanks for the reply, this actually led me down the right path! I noticed that my web app was in strict mode and was firing off 2 api requests in quick succession. Once I tested this in a prod env with no double requests everything worked as expected.